# How to get all cookies from WatIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I am using WatIn to make the login to a website. I need to get all cookies and set them to HttpWebRequest so that I will be able to download a file from this website (bank). I am using Fiddler to see all the cookies and I can see that I am missing some. If I stop my program (debug) and by hard-code insert all cookies from Fiddler to my cookie it will download my files, so that means 100% that I just need to get the cookie from WatIn and my mission is complete.

So how can I get all the cookies?

My code WaTin:

```
using (var browser = new IE("https://bankxxx.com"))
{
    try
    {
        browser.WaitForComplete();
        try
        {
            //  browser.Visible = false;
            browser.TextField(Find.ById("userID")).TypeText(strUser);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            browser.TextField(Find.ById("numID")).Value = strUserId;
            browser.TextField(Find.ById("userPassword")).TypeText(strPass);
            linkExist = browser.Image(Find.ById("inputSend")).Exists;
            if (linkExist) browser.Image(Find.ById("inputSend")).Click();
            browser.WaitForComplete();
            linkExist = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            successful = false;
            clsUtils.WriteToLog("Fail to connect -" + ex.Message, true);
            ErrorLog += "Fail to connect -" + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        //Here i am in side of WebSite
        //I tried this too,i getting the same cookie
        //CookieContainer cookies23 = browser.GetCookieContainerForUrl(new Uri("bank.com"));
        //CookieCollection cookies34 = browser.GetCookiesForUrl(new Uri("bank"));
        string cookies = browser.Eval("document.cookie");
        CookieContainer _cookies = GeneralUtils.GetCc(cookies, "bank.com");
        //then my httpreqest NOT FUll it is working 100% if cookies is good
        HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("bank.com");
        postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        postRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;.......
    }
```

My GetCc function than build CookieContainer from string and add domain:

```
public static CookieContainer GetCc(string cookie, string Domain)
    {
        CookieContainer Cc = new CookieContainer();
        string[] arrCookie;
        string[] allcookies = cookie.Split(';');
        for (int i = 0; i < allcookies.Length; i++)
        {
            arrCookie = allcookies[i].Split('=');
            Cookie TCookie = new Cookie();
            TCookie.Name = arrCookie[0].Trim().ToString();
            TCookie.Value = arrCookie[1].Trim().ToString();
            TCookie.Domain = Domain;
            Cc.Add(TCookie);
        }
        return Cc;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution?